# DHCPのIPが割り当てられてるローカルネットワーク内の機器に固有名を指定する方法

Tags: raspberry-pi

Macで使われている技術でDHCPでIPが割り当てられてるローカルネットワーク内で特定のノードに固定名を指定する方法がLinuxでも使えると聞いたのですが、その名前を忘れてしまいました。

Raspberry Piに固有名を与えるために使おうと考えています。

Comment: dhcp関連だとIPアドレスの固定リースが浮かびますが、[Zeroconf](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf)周りでしょうか？

Comment: Zeroconfでも同様のことができるのかもしれませんが、Avahiが探していたものでしたので、そちらを Accept させて頂きました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linuxでの名前はAvahiではないでしょうか。

Comment: 探していたものはまさにこれです！ありがとうございました。